# how to align NSMutableArray objects to different labels?

Tags: xcode, random, nsmutablearray

I want to show array objects at the same time in different 10 labels. They should be align random for every time. How can I do that?

I've done the random part:

```
srandom(time(NULL));
NSUInteger arr = [myarray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr; ++i) {
    int nElements = arr - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    [myarray exchangeObjectAtIndex: i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

But when I want to use the code below to 10 different labels, array objects repeat, and 2 or 3 different labels can have the same value. How can I make them different?

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arr objectAtIndex:(random()%9)+1]intValue];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are uses the random() method to randomise the objects into array then no need to use the random() for displaying the data in labels as in randome method some returned data can be repeatedly returned so this happens just use random() for randomize the data and serially show  them in labels using simple for loop.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But how can I put the 10 labels and other 10 objects on a loop. Should I make an array from labels too? Sorry for these simple questions I'm a beginner

Comment: I'm trying this, but still get the same error.Labels are not unique they can have the same value=( 'for (int y=1; y<11; y++) {
    
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d", y];  
        UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:name];'

Comment: First just create the array and labels and at the first time creation of labels just add them to one mutable array and after that just again rendamize the mutable array and show labels using the for loop